# htaccess - Redirect to the same location irrespective of presence of trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following sets of links:

1. **a/b/c** or **a/b/c/** to **a.php?b=c**
2. **x/y1/z1/y2/z2** or **x/y1/z1/y2/z2/** to **x.php?y1=z1&y2=z2**

using htaccess and mod rewrite in a standardized general format associating the appropriate PHP get tags and values to the corresponding SEO-friendly link. How do I do so?

I've tried tinkering around with RewriteCond and REQUEST_FILENAME but just cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Just slap `/?` on the end of the match (i.e. `a/b/c/?`); it uses a regex so that'll match 0 or 1 instances of `/` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1.php?$2=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1.php?$2=$3&$4=$5
```

Comment: The content loads but the relative paths (images, css) do not seem to work.

Comment: can you please give one exact path that does not load

Comment: This is what I have in my a.php: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Comment: I fixed that by adding a <base> inside the <head> tag. This is how my htaccess file looks like right now:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?p=$1&id=$2&start=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?p=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?p=$1 [L]` only one rule seems to work at a time (i.e. if I comment out two other rules)

Comment: First, I really think there should be `+` instead of  `*` in last 3 rules

Comment: Also, other rules seem totally different from your original question